# getCurrentSession() vs openSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, genericdao, hibernate-generic-dao

I'm trying to use generic-dao (http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/ ). However, in my HibernateBaseDAO the getSession() method is implemented as sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). This leads to an error for any entity update

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction
```

However, when I use openSession() in place of getCurrentSession(), it works. I'm not using spring as a dependency in pom.xml. I've been reading on openSession() and getCurrentSession(), however still can't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Have you specified hibernate to use the ThreadLocalSessionContext?

Comment: yes I've specified ThreadLocalSessionContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, with genericDAO it gets the current session which needs to be explicitly open using openSession(), while getCurrentSession() just attaches it to the [current session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29). According to the author

> GenericDAO makes the assumption that you will be handling transactions
>   externally to the DAO

Answer (score 0):

The `currentSession` turns out in many situations to be very fragile.

You may have undefined state after an error, so please make sure that your "current session" and transaction was not destroyed by a previous error. to achive this, print out the transaction state (`isActive`) just before using calling `getCurrentSession` inside the DAO.

Double-check that the `SessionContext` is configured and working; call `getCurrentSession` twice and check if returned instances are same, if not, you may are looking at different sessions:

```
assert getCurrentSession()==getCurrentSession()
```

I learned hard lessons to be very conservative with Hibernate. So spending some time on basics really pays off.